# Elijah's Presence

Tags: passover, brit-milah, eliyahu-hanavi

I do not have the source for this, but have heard that Elijah the Prophet attends every Brit Milah.

In [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTRDmLAdjrY) by Yosef Mizrachi, in the first 2 minutes he goes on to say that even after the Brit Milah, Elijah the Prophet's presence lingers for 3 days after.

Can someone supply the source for this idea about Brit Milah.

My question is: **How should one understand the idea that Elijah attends Brit Milah or the Passover Seder if he didn't die and remained with a physical body?**

Comment: is this really two questions -- the three days, and how to understand the idea? ... if so, it would be ideally split into two questions

Comment: for the seder, see here, that it seems to be mistaken. https://jewishaction.com/religion/shabbat-holidays/passover/whats-the-truth-about-eliyahu-hanavi-at-the-seder/

Comment: for brit milah, there are sources for him coming to a brit. Pirkei d’Rebbi Eliezer (chap. 29) Separately, there's an idea, midrashically, of the third day after the brit being most painful. I'd imagine there's some source for Eliyahu Hanavi sticking around based on that, but don't know it.

Comment: finally, here's a source, but I don't know the source's source: https://www.yahadut26.org/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94
Look for the word שלשה.
They are careful not to discuss idle matters, because there's a tradition that Eliyahu HaNavi manifests there. And they place the kisei shel Eliyahu three days BEFORE the brit for this reason, and (later on that page) three days after

Comment: @joshwaxman it is not 2 questions, it is one question asking how do we understanding the spirit of Elijah coming if he ascended into heaven with a body? does his soul leave the body? does body not mean body?

Comment: Eliyahu Ha'navi is the universal timeless spirit of the Jewish people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary question (bolded by the author) was this:

> How should one understand the idea that Elijah attends Brit Milah or the Passover Seder if he didn't die and remained with a physical body?

To restate it, Eliyahu has a body. A specific belief / midrash is that Eliyahu is present at a brit milah. Yet, I look and I don't see him. How can this midrash be literally true, when it contradicts our senses?

A ready answer is that within the framework of this midrash, Eliyahu is invisible, despite possessing a physical body. You can listen to this short shiur by Rabbi Stuart Halpern about [Pinchas as an invisible spy](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/902407).

As background, [Yehoshua 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.2.4?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) states about Rachav hiding the spies, who midrashically are Pinchas and Kalev:

> תִּקַּ֧ח הָאִשָּׁ֛ה אֶת־שְׁנֵ֥י הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים וַֽתִּצְפְּנ֑וֹ וַתֹּ֣אמֶר ׀ כֵּ֗ן בָּ֤אוּ אֵלַי֙ הָאֲנָשִׁ֔ים וְלֹ֥א יָדַ֖עְתִּי מֵאַ֥יִן הֵֽמָּה׃
> And the woman took the two men, and hid them, and said thus, There came men to me, but I know not from where they were:

The language is strange because vatitzpino is the singular, she hid **him**, rather than them. Rashi explains:

> And she hid them. There are scriptural verses that speak of the plural as if it were singular. Since she was in a hurry to hide them and she hid them in a narrow place it was as though they were one person. The Midrash of Rabbi Tanchuma states ‘That these two men were Pinchos and Caleiv, and Pinchos stood before them but they did not see him because he was [invisible] like an angel.’ Another interpretation: She hid each of them separately. We find a similar verse: ‘Oil and incense gladden the heart’ and it does not say יְשַׂמְחוּ לֵב, in the plural.

So we know that Pinchas can make himself invisible. Meanwhile, [many midrashim](https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/parsha/is-pinchas-really-eliyahu/2014/07/11/) say that Pinchas and Eliyahu are the same person. When Pinchas was rewarded with *berit kehunat olam*, that was not dying and indeed becoming Eliyahu HaNavi.

So, a physical Eliyahu can be present, just not visible.

Comment: This is brilliant, along with your comments I have just seen this sufficiently answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full story that Josh Waxman mentioned.  Elijah is always present at a circumcision because when he was hiding in a cave, God visited him and asked him:
Why are you here, Elijah? [1 Kings 19:9]
He replied:

> I am moved by zeal for the Lord, the God of Hosts, for the Israelites have forsaken Your covenant [brit], torn down Your altars, and put Your prophets to the sword. I alone am left, and they are out to take my life. [1 Kings 19:10, 14]

God resented Elijah for badmouthing Israel.  The Zohar says:

> God said to [Elijah:]…  The mouth that accused Israel of forsaking the covenant shall testify that they are observing it.  [Zohar 1:93a]

So the rabbis concluded that Elijah must be present at every circumcision to satisfy himself that the Jews indeed fulfill that commandment.  The Midrash says:

> Hence the sages instituted [the custom] that people should have a seat of honor for [Elijah at every circumcision]; for Elijah, may he be remembered for good, is called the Messenger of the Covenant, as it is said [in Malachi]:

> The messenger of the covenant [brit], that you desire, is coming. [Mal. 3:1]

[Pirkei D’Rabbi Eliezer 29]

Comment: +1 commenting to add that this half answers the first of the questions, namely the source. But the question was worded that he also wants the source for Yosef Mizrachi's mentioned addition, three days after, when the brit is held in a house. And also doesn't answer the more fundamental question #2, namely if Eliyahu is present, why can we not see him, if after all, a read of the original Tanach story indicated that he ascended to Heaven while keeping his body.